# Achieve Full Outer Join Effect Without Duplicating Columns In SQLite JDBC

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc

It might have already been answered but I couldn't find what I was looking for. So a new question.

I am trying to create Full OUTER JOIN in SQLite JDBC using below syntax.

**SQLite Query That I tried:**

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.*
FROM   table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 
ON table1.ID = table2.ID
AND
table1.Name = table2.Name
UNION ALL
SELECT table1.*, table2.*
FROM   table2
LEFT JOIN table1
ON table1.ID = table2.ID
AND
table1.Name = table2.Name
```

Then it produces duplicate columns (as expected in Full Outer Join though). However, It would be great to get only one instance of those duplicate columns i.e. Union without repeat columns.

**More Explanation:** What I need is to get all columns from both tables except repeating the duplicate columns.

Any suggestion would help a lot.

Comment: I assume you mean rows, not columns?

Comment: Hmm sorry if I am not good with explaining what I want, but the result gives me two ID columns and two Name columns.

So I precisely mean columns here, unless I am missing some basic SQL concept.

Comment: And you don't want to list all columns manually?

Comment: Well there are a lot of other columns would be funny to write down all those and might be bad in case if I want to change something in future. Which would be a source of potential mistake.

I do not have much experience with SQL, so there might be another way of what I am trying to achieve, would be great if you could point me in right direction.

Comment: IF you truly mean columns, what you're asking for can't be done unless you explicitly list the columns manually.  Here's why.. name exists in table1 and table2 as does ID.  so both tables are reporting name and ID because you are using `*`  There's not a way in SQL to say give me `*` except some columns.  If this was MySQL, it would automatically eliminate the columns with duplicate name only taking the first.  By MSFT products don't do this.

Comment: @xQbert USING would remove some column(s) from `*`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the `using` clause for this purpose:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 
     USING(ID, Name)
UNION
SELECT *
FROM   table2 LEFT JOIN
       table1
       USING(ID, Name);
```

Note that the correct equivalent uses `union` rather than `union all`, so duplicates are eliminated.  This also assumes that the only columns with common names are `id` and `name`.

The method that I normally use for a `full outer join` is slightly different:

```
select *
from (select id, name from table1 union
      select id, name from table2
     ) driver left join
     table1
     using (id, name) left join
     table2
     using (id, name);
```

Comment: `Error: SELECTs to the left and right of UNION ALL do not have the same number of result columns` (because USING removes columns only for `*`, not `table1.*`)

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: Your first answer works well with some slight changes. Thanks. I will post another answer that I formed from your answer.

Comment: The USING syntax tip was a brilliant direction.

Answer (score 1):

There is no SQL syntax that selects all columns *except* some columns

```
select * except id, name -- can't do this
```

You must explicitly name all the *other* columns of one of the tables:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.col1, table2.col2, table2.col3 -- etc 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 
  ON table1.ID = table2.ID
  AND table1.Name = table2.Name
UNION ALL
SELECT table1.*, table2.col1, table2.col2, table2.col3 -- etc 
FROM table2
LEFT JOIN table1
  ON table1.ID = table2.ID
  AND table1.Name = table2.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Gordon Linoff [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25550920/1584507), I was able to achieve exactly what I needed.
The magical **syntax** missing was **USING**

**Here it is:**

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 
USING (ID, Name)
```

This does give me all the columns from both tables without repeating duplicate columns.

Comment: But the order of columns is different in the two queries.

Comment: Well I get all the columns from Table1 first then the rest from Table2. On the other hand, I don't really care about the order of columns because I identify them from column names not order.

In addition, both the tables contain the same kind of information and that's why I am trying to join them and write out in a single Excel Workbook Sheet.

Comment: The result of the query has only a single column name per column (the column names of the second subquery have no effect).

Comment: Yes I got your point, the columns then repeat in rows. So In short I don't even need UNION ALL and hence the second sub-query.

Updating the answer now.